# SSRS 2012 - Evaluating multiple parameters against OLAP

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx, olap

I’m very new to MDX. I have a multi-select parameter called @MeasureType that has 3 possible labels (I know the name is confusing but "Measure" is an industry term here):

- CMS
- HEDIS
- CMS/HEDIS

@MeasureType needs to limit the results of two columns: MeasureType and ContractType.

The parameter values map verbatim to MeasureType.  In order to map them to ContractType, we need to apply some logic.  Here’s the logic:

- If @MeasureType = “CMS” then Column2 should be “CMS”
- If @MeasureType = “HEDIS” then Column2 should be “HEDIS”
- If @MeasureType = “CMS/HEDIS” then Column2 should be “CMS” or “HEDIS”
- If @MeasureType is Select All then Column2 should be “CMS” or “HEDIS” or “Other”

Just to make the logic clear, here’s how you could write it in SQL (there are better ways to write it, but it gets the point across):

```
-- Mimic multi-value parameter as if the user chose SELECT ALL
DECLARE @MeasureType TABLE (ParmValue varchar(20))

    INSERT @MeasureType VALUES ('CMS')
    INSERT @MeasureType VALUES ('HEDIS')
    INSERT @MeasureType VALUES ('CMS/HEDIS')

-- Mimic the logic to assign value(s) @ContractType based on user's selection of @MeasureType
DECLARE @ContractType TABLE (ParmValue varchar(20))

    IF (SELECT 1 FROM @MeasureType WHERE ParmValue = 'CMS') = 1 
        INSERT @ContractType VALUES ('CMS')

    IF (SELECT 1 FROM @MeasureType WHERE ParmValue = 'HEDIS') = 1
        INSERT @ContractType VALUES ('HEDIS')

    IF (SELECT 1 FROM @MeasureType WHERE ParmValue = 'CMS/HEDIS') = 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT @ContractType VALUES ('CMS')
            INSERT @ContractType VALUES ('HEDIS')
        END

    IF (SELECT 1 FROM @MeasureType WHERE ParmValue = 'CMS') = 1
    AND (SELECT 1 FROM @MeasureType WHERE ParmValue = 'HEDIS') = 1
    AND (SELECT 1 FROM @MeasureType WHERE ParmValue = 'CMS/HEDIS') = 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT @ContractType VALUES ('CMS')
            INSERT @ContractType VALUES ('HEDIS')
            INSERT @ContractType VALUES ('Other')
        END

-- Get the results
SELECT MeasureType,
       Measure1,
       Measure2
FROM   Table1
WHERE  MeasureType IN (SELECT ParmValue from @MeasureType)
AND    ContractType IN (SELECT ParmVaque from @ContractType)
```

I've tried a couple of approaches.

The first was creating a second (hidden) parameter for @ContractType, which I set using a series of IIFs that evaluate Parameters!MeasureType.Label.  The expression is this:

```
=IIF(
JOIN(Parameters!MeasureType.Label) = "CMS CMS/HEDIS HEDIS", 
"[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS] [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS] [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[Other]",
IIF( INSTR( JOIN(Parameters!MeasureType.Label), "CMS/HEDIS" ), 
    "[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS] [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]",
     IIF( INSTR( JOIN(Parameters!MeasureType.Label), "CMS" ), 
     "[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS]",
     "[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]" )
) )
```

Then I declared both parameters in the Parameters tab of the dataset.  I can run the MDX in the query designer but when I try to preview the report, I get this error… “The syntax for ‘[HealthPlan]’ is incorrect.” So I figured there must be something wrong with the parameter construct.  I created a couple of textboxes to see the contents of the parameters.  When SELECT ALL is chosen, JOIN(Parameters!MeasureType.Value) looks like this:

- [Measure].[MeasureType].&[CMS] [Measure].[MeasureType].&[HEDIS] [Measure].[MeasureType].&[CMS/HEDIS]"

and Parameters!ContractType.Value looks like this:

- [Measure].[MeasureType].&[CMS] [Measure].[MeasureType].&[HEDIS] [Measure].[MeasureType].&[Other]"

which seems correct.  Here's the MDX I'm using for this approach...

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Physician Count], 
                   [Measures].[Population], 
                   [Measures].[Unmet],[Measures].[Met] } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { (NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation1].[Affiliation1].Members, 
                       [Measures].[Population]) *
              NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation2].[Affiliation2].Members, 
                       [Measures].[Population]) *
              NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation3].[Affiliation3].Members, 
                       [Measures].[Population]) *
              NONEMPTY([Measure].[Registry].[Registry].Members, 
                       [Measures].[Population]) * 
              NONEMPTY(([Measure].[Measure].[Measure].Members,
                        [Measure].[MeasureKey].[MeasureKey].Members,
                        IIf (
                          StrToSet ( @MeasureType, CONSTRAINED ) .Count = 1,
                          StrToSet ( @MeasureType, CONSTRAINED ),
                          [Measure].[MeasureType].Members
                             )

                        ), [Measures].[Population]) *
              NONEMPTY(([Physician].[PCPNameCode].[PCPNameCode].Members, 
                        [Physician].[PCPID].[PCPID].Members, 
                        [Specialty].[Specialty].[Specialty].Members
                        ), [Measures].[Population]) ) 
            } 
              DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM (
  SELECT ( StrToSet ( @MeasureType, CONSTRAINED ) ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM (
        SELECT ( StrToSet ( @ContractType, CONSTRAINED ) ) ON COLUMNS
        FROM [Model]
        )
      )
WHERE ( 
    IIf (
      StrToSet ( @ContractType, CONSTRAINED ) .Count = 1,
      StrToSet ( @ContractType, CONSTRAINED ),
      [HealthPlan].[ContractType].CurrentMember
    ) )
CELL Properties Value,BACK_COLOR,FORE_COLOR,FORMATTED_VALUE,FORMAT_STRING,FONT_NAME,FONT_SIZE,FONT_FLAGS
```

Another approach I tried is evaluating @MeasureType within MDX by creating a calculated member with a case statement.  The MDX is below.  When I run it, I get no results at all.

```
WITH MEMBER [HealthPlan].[ContractType].[ContractType2] 
AS
                CASE @MeasureType
                        WHEN "CMS" THEN "[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS]"
                        WHEN "CMS/HEDIS" THEN "[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS] [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]"
                        WHEN "HEDIS" THEN "[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]"
                        WHEN "CMS CMS/HEDIS HEDIS" THEN "[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS] [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS] [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[Other]"
                END

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Physician Count], [Measures].[Population], [Measures].[Unmet],[Measures].[Met] } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { (NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation1].[Affiliation1].Members, [Measures].[Population]) *
                          NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation2].[Affiliation2].Members, [Measures].[Population]) *
                          NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation3].[Affiliation3].Members, [Measures].[Population]) *
                          NONEMPTY([Measure].[Registry].[Registry].Members, [Measures].[Population]) * 
                          NONEMPTY(([Measure].[Measure].[Measure].Members,
                                                [Measure].[MeasureKey].[MeasureKey].Members,
                                                IIf (
                                                  StrToSet ( @MeasureType, CONSTRAINED ) .Count = 1,
                                                  StrToSet ( @MeasureType, CONSTRAINED ),
                                                  [Measure].[MeasureType].Members
                                                         )
                                                ), [Measures].[Population]) *
                          NONEMPTY(([Physician].[PCPNameCode].[PCPNameCode].Members, 
                                                [Physician].[PCPID].[PCPID].Members, 
                                                [Specialty].[Specialty].[Specialty].Members
                                                ), [Measures].[Population]) ) 
                        } 
                          DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [Model]
WHERE [HealthPlan].[ContractType].[ContractType2] 
CELL Properties Value,BACK_COLOR,FORE_COLOR,FORMATTED_VALUE,FORMAT_STRING,FONT_NAME,FONT_SIZE,FONT_FLAGS
```

I’m lost at this point.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hidden Parameter approach should work. The correct syntax for creating an MDX set is:

```
{[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS], [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]}
```

To test just the parameters, use as short a query as possible, maybe something like the following

```
SELECT  { 
     [Measures].[Population] 
 } ON COLUMNS,
StrToSet ( @MeasureType, CONSTRAINED ) 
  ON ROWS
FROM [Model]
```

If you have problems, try building the MDX query in SSMS. Using SSMS, you can quickly check if the Syntax for the set above is correct (it might not be, as I didn't have a cube to test it on!) :

```
  SELECT  { 
    [Measures].[Population] 
   } ON COLUMNS,
   StrToSet ( '{[HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[CMS], [HealthPlan].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]}', 
  CONSTRAINED ) 
  ON ROWS
  FROM [Model]
```

Once you know which text you need to build the set, you can set up a reporting Services Expression to build the text.

Comment: Just to add to this. We tend to build the set expression in code in the SSRS Expression and thus pass it completely to the query so a simple STRTOSET is all that's needed.

Comment: This is working! What I needed was the correct syntax for the members within the parameter set. In regard to what you said above, do you mean that you build the MDX within the dataset expression and concatenate the parameter into the statement?  If so, is there a benefit to doing it that way rather than referring to the parameter within the MDX as @Parm?

Comment: No, Keep the @Param, that is the way to go. I just wanted to show how you can build these things up in smaller steps. If you first use a string in SSMS, then you can much more easily get the MDX query to work as you want. Then you can parameterize it in a second step.

Comment: Thanks so much to the both of you!  I'll post what I ended up with, in case anyone reading is interested.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that worked for me.  Setting @ContractType with the right syntax was the key.  Thanks to Fillet!

@ContractType is set to...

```
=IIF(
JOIN(Parameters!MeasureType.Label) = "CMS CMS/HEDIS HEDIS", 
"{[Member].[ContractType].&[CMS], [Member].[ContractType].&[HEDIS], [Member].[ContractType].&[Other]}",
IIF( INSTR( JOIN(Parameters!MeasureType.Label), "CMS/HEDIS" ), 
    "{[Member].[ContractType].&[CMS], [Member].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]}",
     IIF( INSTR( JOIN(Parameters!MeasureType.Label), "CMS" ), 
     "{[Member].[ContractType].&[CMS]}",
     "{[Member].[ContractType].&[HEDIS]}" )
) )
```

The MDX I'm using is...

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Physician Count], [Measures].[Population], [Measures].[Unmet],[Measures].[Met] } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { (NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation1].[Affiliation1].Members, [Measures].[Population]) *
              NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation2].[Affiliation2].Members, [Measures].[Population]) *
              NONEMPTY([Affiliation].[Affiliation3].[Affiliation3].Members, [Measures].[Population]) *
              NONEMPTY(
                        (
                            [Measure].[Registry].[Registry].Members, 
                            [Measure].[Measure].[Measure].Members,
                            [Measure].[MeasureKey].[MeasureKey].Members,
                            StrToSet ( @MeasureType )
                          ), [Measures].[Population] 
                       ) *
              NONEMPTY(
                        (
                            StrToSet ( @ContractType )
                          ), [Measures].[Population] 
                       ) *
              NONEMPTY(
                        ([Physician].[PCPNameCode].[PCPNameCode].Members, 
                        [Physician].[PCPID].[PCPID].Members, 
                        [Physician].[Specialty].[Specialty].Members
                         ), [Measures].[Population]
                       ) 
             )
            } 
              DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [Model]
```